# Postgres alter table defaults to 'NULL::character varying' instead of NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, heidisql

I am using psql to alter a database table. Currently running the following alter-statement:

```
ALTER TABLE "devices" ADD "device_id" VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

but I end up with the following in the create-table-statement:

```
"device_id" VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT 'NULL::character varying'
```

Why is the default set to `'NULL::character varying'` ?

I am bit confused, since the table already have multiple varchar fields, where the default is correct.. ex from CREATE-statement:

```
"external_id" VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
```

FYI: This column, `external_id`, was created multiple years ago before I started to touch the table.

Comment: How do you generate the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: Currently i am using HeidiSQL to view the data and CREATE-statement

Comment: Looks like a HeidiSQL bug: https://i.imgur.com/Nfyrimt.png

Comment: just checked, and this is also what `\d+` is telling me in `psql`.. so no its not HeidiSQL

Comment: The you probably used `default 'NULL'` not what you put in the question.

Comment: nope i use the statement written in the question.

Comment: Well, there must be something you are not telling us, because in this works as expected, see [this screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Nfyrimt.png)

Comment: your picture shows the same, I experience.
I run the alter statement, i want a VARCHAR(255) which defaults to NULL.. but instead the default is `NULL::character varying`.. which your image also shows.. and i am asking why this is?

Comment: I don't get it, since there is older columns in the table which does not default to `NULL::character varying` but just `NULL`, which to my knowledge is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you explicitly set the default value to NULL, PostgreSQL has added a column default. Default values are *not* stored in string form, but they are parsed and stored as a *parse tree* (in binary form). When you display the table definition, PostgreSQL “deparses” this information, which results in the (equivalent) `NULL::character varying` (the `::` is a type cast).

That is just fine, but if you find it optically displeasing, you can simply drop the default value:

```
ALTER TABLE devices ALTER device_id DROP DEFAULT;
```

That will get rid of the default value, which won't change the behavior (the “default default value” is NULL).

Comment: But `'NULL::character varying'` (which is what Thor claims to see) is something different than `NULL::character varying` (which is what he expects)

Comment: The CREATE-statement in HeidiSQL displays this default value as a string yes.. and i just copy pasted it to here.. but the psql statement displays it as just `NULL::character varying` without the single-quotes, so everything is fine.. i was just wondering why some of my columns in the CREATE-statement was: `.. DEFAULT NULL, ...` and some was `DEFAULT 'NULL::character varying', ...`. But it looks like it is "just" type casting. 

The only question that remains for me is.. how come the old/prev. columns be defined as `DEFAULT NULL` and not  `DEFAULT 'NULL::character varying'` ?

Comment: How do these old default values look in `psql` when you display the table definition with `\d`?

Comment: shouldn't they all be `DEFAULT 'NULL::character varying'` ?.. even if the old/prev. columns was created on an older version of the DB

Comment: This has nothing to do with the version - the difference is if you set a default value or not.

Comment: psql shows the following for the device_id: https://i.imgur.com/OojvKqI.png - and for the old/prev. columns: https://i.imgur.com/Xeh6rxA.png - and HeidiSQL displays them as following: https://i.imgur.com/6csFB5S.png

Comment: That confirms that you defined the "old columns" without specifying a default value, while you used `DEFAULT NULL` for the "new columns".

Comment: cool.. i did not create these columns, which was why i was curious.. they where also created with django's ORM.. where it is specified the column is allowed to be null.. but no default was set (specified in python-code).